# Why zoom level returns decimal?

Tags: openlayers

I use openlayers 6 in my project.
Layers on the map hide/show acording to zoom level.

Here is map and view defenitions:

```js
view = new View({
    center: mapCenter,
    projection: israeliTM.getCode(),
    zoom: 0,
    resolutions: resolutions // resolutions array 
});

map = new Map({
    layers: layers,
    target: 'map',
    view: view
});
```

This row is fired when zoom is changed:

```js
var curRes = map.getView().getResolution()[map.getView().getZoom()];
```

As you can see on view defenition resolutions defined as array and when zoom is changed 
I expect to get from this `map.getView().getZoom()` integer number that displays index in 
resolutions array and return current resolution. In general it works as expected but sometimes
`map.getView().getZoom()` returns decimal number like 3.56989.

Any idea why `map.getView().getZoom()` returns some time decimal?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using OpenLayers 6 specify `constrainResolution` in the view options

```
view = new View({
    center: mapCenter,
    projection: israeliTM.getCode(),
    zoom: 0,
    constrainResolution: true,
    resolutions: resolutions // resolutions array 
});
```

and for OpenLayers 5 specify `constrainResolution` in the interaction options

```
map = new Map({
    layers: layers,
    target: 'map',
    interactions: defaultInteractions({
        constrainResolution: true
    }),
    view: view
});
```

Comment: Mike thaks for post. Any can I use instaed of rsolutions array  (resolutions: resolutions) array of scales as it was possible in ol2?

Comment: You can use a resolutions array to define the zoom levels (it's the only way if they are irregularly spaced) but the view is not constrained to integer values unless you also specify constrainResolution.

Comment: Still I get same behavior, I get  zoom 1.99998 after adding constrainResolution: true

Comment: Zooming is animated by default so you will see non-integer values while that is happening. To avoid that you could try using `zoomDuration: 0` in the interaction options  https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction.html#~defaults

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior and it actually returns a `Number()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

This change seems to have appeared with the gl version as you now don't have defined zoom levels.

Interesting to note is that whenever the map zoom control (+ -) UI buttons are used, the value appears to always increase/decrease to the next whole number integer (e.g. 3.462 would become 3.0 or 4.0) but when a pinch-to-zoom event occurs, the values generally contain a decimal portion.

If you want it to be whole number step based then check out:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/7863

specifically:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/7863/commits/19b164205208e99bbbd62750cfb7e845819ab8e4